# Explore a Klarner-Rado sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, array, linear-algebra

One of the Klarner-Rado sequences is defined as follows:

- the first term is \$1\$
- for all subsequent terms, the following rule applies: if \$x\$ is present, so are \$2x+1\$ and \$3x+1\$
- the sequence is strictly increasing

This is [A002977](https://oeis.org/A002977).

The first few terms are:

```
1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, 27, ...
```

(\$3\$ is present because it's \$2\times1+1\$, \$4\$ is present because it's \$3\times1+1\$, \$7\$ is present because it's \$2\times3+1\$, etc.)

#### Your task

Given \$n\$, you must return the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> element of the sequence. You may use either 0-based or 1-based indexing. (Please specify your choice in your answer.)

*0-indexed example:*

```
input = 10
output = 22
```

Let's see who can get less bytes...

*<sub>Also featured on [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5672682212c8ecf83e000050/train/)</sub>*

Comment: Why is this tagged [javascript]? Is this restricted to it? How is this related to array manipulation and linear algebra? Does "ordered with <" mean "ascending"?

Comment: Apart from the arbitrary language restriction there isn't any problem.

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058/69850 -- you can "look at the challenge as a separate competition in each language".

Comment: @Arnauld and what's with that? I solved the problem but I want to see community's inventions

Comment: @user89702 It's not yours, so you can't post it, especially without any attribution.

Comment: Why so strict? Is just a challenge, if you don't want to participate just ignore this post, let people have fun

Comment: However, I do believe this is a rather interesting challenge that would be worth rephrasing properly for Code Golf. There's nothing wrong on posting a challenge about this sequence (which is [A002977](https://oeis.org/A002977), btw), but you can't copy from an external site without any authorization or credits.

Comment: I want to agree with @user89702. Two of my top posts are not my challenge, but they get upvotes.

Comment: I've rephrased your post so that it better fits our standard and is not a copy of codewars anymore. Feel free to edit further if needed.

Comment: [closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85411/34531)

Comment: Currently this needs to mention that this sequence is in ascending order.  Without it the only term that we can know the location of is the first one.

Comment: I upvoted & closed as a duplicate (even though slightly different). This could get reopened if people think the offset difference is enough to make answers not trivially portable.

Comment: How do we define duplicate? This question: If x occurs in the sequence, then 2x+1 and 3x+1 also exists. Claimed duplicate:If x occurs in the sequence, then 2x+1 and 3x-1 also exists. Are the two definitions sufficiently close to count as a duplicate. Rules Committee????

Comment: I made the comment above as it is exceedingly frustrating to spend the time to answer a question only to find some considerable time later it is claimed to be a duplicate. Personally I do not have the time or inclination to validate every question before answering it.

Comment: @Graham, if you've taken the time to work up a solution then absolutely post it to the dupe target. If your solution cannot be trivially modified to fit the dupe target then you have a case to reopen this one and you should cast your vote accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
$FDx>DŠ+)˜ê}sè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fxc2lws7l6AJtzdNzDq@qLT684v9/QwMA)

Comment: Times out for me on TIO for inputs of 14 and above

Comment: @Graham Well this is code golf, not fastest code, so that’s not an issue.

Comment: @Graham, for the purposes of code golf, we may assume infinite memory & time.

Comment: @Grimy Thanks to you and Shaggy for this information which I had not appreciated. All solutions I have offered in the past have worked efficiently within the capabilities of my machine. This opens up some wacky impractical solutions ;)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>53</s>  50 bytes

1-indexed.

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>n?g(g[k]|!k++?g[n--,k*2]=g[k*3]=k:k):k)``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYpBCsIwEEX3PcUIXUwaI1V31mkPUgIJtQ2aMpFW3MScPQY@vMfjv@zX7tP2fH8Uh8ecF8pMPTry1PPg0I1e/w5eysGNrNTRNxdNJTZXTf7mRZkxeQkbMhCcO2C4F7ZtMSkFxApgCryHdT6twaGxWEdOopzruCCLZERXpfwH)

#### Commented

**Note**: On the first iteration, we have `k = ['']`, which is zero-ish but truthy. By doing `!k++`, we force `k` to be coerced to \$0\$ *right away* (and  not just before it's incremented), which makes the test work as expected.

```javascript
n => (                    // n = requested index
  g = k =>                // h is a recursive function taking k, starting at 0
    n ?                   // if n is not equal to 0:
      g(                  //   do a recursive call:
        g[k] |            //     if g[k] is defined
        !k++ ?            //     or k = 0 (increment k after the test):
          g[n--, k * 2] = //       decrement n; set g[k * 2]
          g[k * 3] = k    //       and g[k * 3] and pass k
        :                 //     else:
          k               //       just pass k
      )                   //   end of recursive call
    :                     // else:
      k                   //   stop recursion and return k
)``                       // initial call to g with k = [''] (zero-ish)
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 65 bytes

I thought the `'11'[k/x-2]` trick was neat, but overall this initial approach is far too long.

0-indexed.

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>a[n]||g(-~k,a.some(x=>'11'[k/x-2])&&a.push(k+1)))(a=[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBDoIwEADAO6/YA4HdIEi9YvkIIWGDgFrcEqqGBPDrVW9zmDu/2bXzbXqmYi@d77UXXeKgjS65knrbBkw/5sCZs48OF13GSsWVOS7pqaYo4mx6uSuaRBERsq5UTb63MwpoyAsQOIPK/0gSgjUAaK04O3bZaAdsGMNVdvrdcO1RaG@oCHb/BQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => (                  // n = requested index
  g = k =>              // g is a recursive function taking k (starting at 1)
    a[n] ||             // if a[n] is defined, return it and stop
    g(                  // otherwise, do a recursive call:
      -~k,              //   with k + 1
      a.some(x =>       //   if there exists some x in a[]
        '11'[k / x - 2] //   such that k / x is either 2 or 3 ...
      )                 //
      && a.push(k + 1)  //   ... then push k + 1 in a[]
    )                   // end of recursive call
)(a = [1])              // initial call to g with k = a = [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 57 bytes

```r
n=scan();for(i in 1:n)T=sort(unique(c(T,T%o%2:3+1)));T[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTOi2/SCNTITNPwdAqTzPEtji/qESjNC@zsDRVI1kjRCdENV/VyMpY21BTU9M6JDov9r@hwX8A)

1-based index.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 54 bytes

Index origin 1

Prompts for the index of required value. Given the response that I received from Grimy and Shaggy that I can assume infinite memory and time then it is trivial to modify this function to work with a series up to the limit of your machine by increasing the value 20 in the function below. This version is limited to index position 1901981

```
m←1⋄(⍎∊20⍴⊂'m←(0≠1,-2-/m)/m←m[⍋m←m,∊1+m×¨⊂2 3]⋄')⋄m[⎕]
```

For some reason this function will not run on Dyalog Classic in TIO which is what I usually use.

On my machine 1 => 1, 11 => 22 and 61 => 237 (checked on http://oeis.org)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 99 bytes

```
x=>eval("a=[i=1],a.b=a.includes;while(i++,c=i-1,x)a.b(i)||!a.b(c/2)&&!a.b(c/3)||(a.push(i),x--);c")
```

Comment: I think this works for 96 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYq7DsIgFEB3P6MTNzwUHQkd@xPG4UqJvYaUptjK0H9HGjfjds7JeeKKyc00veQYe186W7Jt/YqBNWivZPVNoLpbVDS6sPQ@mfdAwTPiXDhLUosMdWAE26bbndzxDPwLlxqzlNWmJQ31Ma6B4uKYYvAqxAfrmAYwh590@tP2r3wA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah, type casting is fun.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=0,k=[1]:(i==n)*k[i]or f(n,i+1,sorted(k+[2*k[i]+1,3*k[i]+1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcoxDoAgEETRq1AuSiHamexJCAUG0Q26GKTx9EiM3eS/uZ6yJ55qDXi4c/FOsCIcVESj7QyEyLKLhmzKIkCzXqs75bJ6iL0ZP2pp@oeVsoZ2JUEssuNtBa3lfGXiAgGo8Qs)